# import object data using get Node js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, get

I'm having trouble learning how to import data from a site using HTTP get in node js. The GET would be accessing an array of objects contained in the key of root JSON object returned.

Two things that confuse me are how to use my query key in this process/how to act on or access the array information that the get would return. Thanks a lot

My code so far is as follows:

```
var http = require('http');


var options = {
  host: 'site',
  path: 'path'

};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass the query parameter would be to include in the path.

You can define the options like this

```
var options = {
  host: 'site',
  path: 'path?queryparam=parameter'
};
```

as per using the return value, depends on how you want to handle.

If you want to come back to make script and do something you can do it like promise ,

Another way is to pass a call back function to the call back method and execute  (which create the call back hell). something like

```
callback = function(response,callback2) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    callback2(str);
  });
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this way. I would suggest to understand how promise work and implement it, may be with async - await.

Here is a link to nice example 
https://www.tomas-dvorak.cz/posts/nodejs-request-without-dependencies/